# How to replace a link with another set of links in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This question is linked to [How can a Greasemonkey script split a link into three related links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775527/how-can-a-greasemonkey-script-split-a-link-into-three-related-links).

In the answer given (which works) by the way, the method is to modify the initial link and append the other links to it. However it is designed for a  commit comment linked to a single Redmine issue. I modified it so

```
$('a[title]').each( function () {
    redmineURL = getProjectURL($(this).attr('title'));
});
$("a[href*='/commit/']").each ( function () {
    /*-- Parse each link for the expected format:
        refs #{number} {description text}
    */
    var jThis       = $(this);
    if ($(this).text().match(/#\d+\b/g)) {
        var commitText = $(this).text();
        var cgitURL = $(this).attr('href');
        //$(this).text (commitText[1]);
        $(this).after(processLinkedCommit(redmineURL, commitText, cgitURL)); 
    }
} );
```

With this method the original link should be replaced with the output of the function `processLinkedCommit`. `redmineURL` is `Redmine` project with the issue, which is computed from the a 'title' attribute in the page. `commitText` is the text of the commit which is in the link of `Cgit` page and `cgitURL` is the href attribute.

I want to replace the original link with up to about 10 URLs created by `processLinkedCommit`. It appears I will have to delete $(this) and replace it with the list of URLs, ie I have to put it after its previous sibling. How would I do this in jQuery?

Comment: Why bother `var jThis = $(this);` if you're not going to do yourself a favour and use it?

Comment: @DavidBarker It has been deleted in the answer below.

Comment: The fact is it shouldnt be deleted. It should be used instead of the $(this) five times over, 5 jQuery objects is not efficient.

Comment: @DavidBarker I am exploring Javascript - its a good thing to know.

Answer (score 0):

After some more thought and looking up the docs, I came up with this solution. The replacements URLs are appended using the `.after()` function and the original link is removed using the `.remove()` function;

```
$('a[title]').each( function () {
    redmineURL = getProjectURL($(this).attr('title'));
});
$("a[href*='/commit/']").each ( function () {
    if ($(this).text().match(/#\d+\b/g)) {
        var commitText = $(this).text();
        var cgitURL = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).after(processLinkedCommit(redmineURL, commitText, cgitURL)); 
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```